# Updating portion of text file with PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to replace part of text or HTML file with PHP? I'm loading portion of file into text editor by using preg_match to extract text only between certain tags. Now when finish editing I want to update the same file with changes made, and replace the same part previously loaded.

Comment: Yes it is possible to replace a part of text or HTML via PHP.

Comment: You may want to give some code examples or some sample data so we know what we're working with.  Simply asking if it is possible will unlikely lead you to the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @TimWolla: straight answer :)

Comment: I don't have to code. I need to implement it.
1. Open testfile.html
2. Find content between <start> and </end> tags
3. Replace content between tags with new content
4. Save file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you're using preg_match, you can use the preg_replace after editing and store it to the file.

for example if you are loading a UI for that then you might be doing this on file1.php

```
$data = file_get_contents($filename);
//do regex here
$values = preg_match($pattern,$data);
//do necessary display here for the form I assume
```

then on file2.php that receives the request on the form, you do exacly the same thing

```
$data = file_get_contents($filename);
//compose the string to you will have to replace to the pattern
$data = preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$data);
//then write to the same file
file_put_contents($filename,$data);
```

these are just theoretical, kindly check with the php manual for correct syntax or parameters

Comment: Can you please provide the example?